# Order by joined custom table

Tags: custom, product-collection, table, join

I've got a productcollection, which i joined a custom table to. I'd now like to order the collection on the custom joined table row "custom_row_value".

I've tried the below method, but this does not work.

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $_collectProductIds));

$_productCollection
->getSelect()
->join('custom_table', 'custom_table.entity_id = e.entity_id', array('custom_row_value'))
->where('custom_table.category_id='.$_category->getId())
->order('custom_table.custom_row_value','desc');
```

How would i achieve this goal in a neat way?

Comment: What kind of effect are you having? No sorting or errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is correct, what is probably wrong is the `order` direction.

According to `Zend_Db_Select::order` definition you can pass **only one argument**, not two arguments as you are doing in your code.

Your query will be handled regardless the sorting direction and will take `ASC` as default.

Try changing:

```
->order('custom_table.custom_row_value','desc');
```

To

```
->order('custom_table.custom_row_value desc');
```

You can check your query with a simple:

```
echo $_productCollection->getSelect();
```

If it does not work, then you problem is elsewhere IMHO.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are welcome ;)